# Navbar not sticking to the bottom of the header element

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to stick this navbar onto the bottom of a header but it sticks to the top of it instead of the bottom (which I want). The nav should stick to the bottom of the header and stay that way when the user scrolls down.

As of now the header and nav are set to position:fixed and hover over the text as it scrolls down (like it should)...but the nav sticks to the top of the header instead of the bottom, thus cutting off the first part (1) in this case. I'm sure it's super simple but can I get an idea of how to fix that with only css? I'm not sure how to do this for non-nested elements that are fixed (as they don't stack normally)

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>

<nav>
   <ul>
      <li href="#">1</a></li>
      <li href="#">2</a></li>
      <li href="#">3</a></li>                   
   </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 

</main>
</wrapper>
```

html

```
header{
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #333;
   padding-left: .5rem;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding-bottom: 1rem;
   padding-top: 1rem;
   z-index: 100;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  top 0;

   display:block;
   background-color: yellow;
   width: 10rem;
}
```

css

This illustrates what is happening right now: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKbVVX

Comment: typo: `top 0;` should be `top:0;`

Comment: Ty for catching that but it still doesn't solve it

Comment: did you write `</wrapper>` instead of closing the `<div id="wrapper">` with `</div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 48px;
 display:block;
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 10rem;
 }
```

[Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/jrPYxj)

Have `position:relative;` in `wrapper` div and `position:fixed;` in `nav`

Comment: If you use the pen you have it does have the position I want..but if you scroll down it does not keep its fixed position

Comment: I have edited the answer and codepen link see if it works for you now.

Comment: Perfect...I see what you did now. I guess offsetting with top is the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes when you were having adding Top:48px; in nav and position:relative in wrapper is making it position relative to wrapper 48px from top. Please mark the answer accepted if it works for you. It might help others.

Comment: Alright. I appreciate all the help from you guys. You got the answer first so I'm going to have to give the point to you, although the other user gave a similar answer after. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Modified your code a little bit.
Hope this will help

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header {
  margin-top: -16px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333;
  padding-left: .5em;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  z-index: 100;
}
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 10em;
}
main {
  margin-left: 15em;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li href="#">1</li>
      <li href="#">2</li>
      <li href="#">3</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The last closing tag must be `</div>`, not `</wrapper>` and the CSS `top 0;` must be `top: 0;`.

And to make the nav come right under the header, you should give the header an exact height, then use the same number for the `top` of the nav. like this:

```css
header{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   background-color: #333;
   height: 48px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding-left: .5rem;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding-bottom: 1rem;
   padding-top: 1rem;
   z-index: 100;
}

nav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 48px;

   display:block;
   background-color: yellow;
   width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>

<nav>
   <ul>
      <li href="#">1</a></li>
      <li href="#">2</a></li>
      <li href="#">3</a></li>                   
   </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 
   <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p> 

</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Obviously I had some stupid mistakes I really should have caught (my fault), but, again, not doing what I am looking for. To reiterate...I want the top of that yellow border (nav) to stick to the bottom of that grey border (header) keeping the fixed position so it stays glued together when scrolling down

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to place the navigation links *in* the `header` under `nav` and have what you wanted to be the top of the bar in `div`, then style the two differently as you intended originally.

General outline for HTML:

```
<header>
    <div>
        <p>The top of the bar!</p
    </div>
    <nav>
        <uk>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS to go with:

```
header {
    postiion: fixed;
}
header div {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    padding: 2em;
}
header nav {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```